# PHP Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am keep getting this error when I wrote my Email class in php.

```
class Email {

public $mail;

function __construct() {
    $this->$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $this->$mail->SMTPDebug=1;

    $this->$mail->isSMTP();

    $this->$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $this->$mail->Host = '************'

    $this->$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    $this->$mail->Port = 465;

    $this->$mail->Hostname = '************';

    $this->$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $this->$mail->FromName = '*************';

    $this->$mail->Username = '*************';

    $this->$mail->Password = '**************';

    $this->$mail->From ='***********';
}
```

When I new a Email Class, it said cannot access empty property at

```
$this->$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

I have tried to do this

```
public $mail = new PHPMailer();
```

it said it is a syntax error.

Can someone help?

Comment: what about `$this->mail`?

Comment: you mean at the class instance?

Comment: You don't use $ for an instance property.  `$this->name` not `$this->$name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

String prefixed with $ character are being interpreted as variables and this includes accessing class properties through a variable:

Example:

```
$property = 'address';
echo $this->$property;
```

`$property` is being resolved to `address`, therefore `$this->$property` evaluates to `$this->address`.

In your case $mail had no value assigned to it, therefore when accessing `$this->$mail` you were accessing empty property `$this->` and trying to assign:

```
$this-> = new PHPMailer();
```

**Solution:**

Omit the $ character when accessing class properties directly.

```
class Email {

public $mail;

function __construct() {
    $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $this->mail->SMTPDebug=1;

    $this->mail->isSMTP();

    $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $this->mail->Host = '************'

    $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    $this->mail->Port = 465;

    $this->mail->Hostname = '************';

    $this->mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $this->mail->FromName = '*************';

    $this->mail->Username = '*************';

    $this->mail->Password = '**************';

    $this->mail->From ='***********';
}
```

Comment: I believe answers should *explain* what changed and why it changed.